# Difference between Stack Overflow, Pro Webmasters, and Web Applications

Tags: support

I am confused about the differences between [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), and [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/), as questions asked on Pro Webmasters, and Web Applications are also asked on Stack Overflow.

What is different between those Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Why are you confused?

Comment: Because question ask on Pro Webmasters and Web Applications are also asked in stackoverflow so why this is used.what differ those from stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you read the FAQ on each site? Not all questions that belong to one site belong on the others, though there is a subset of questions that will fit all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is reported in their FAQ pages.

#### [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)

> Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange is for professional and enthusiast webmasters. If your question generally covers the operation of websites which you control, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!
>
> Please note that if your question is about detailed HTML, JavaScript, or CSS coding, it might be a better fit on Stack Overflow. We prefer questions here about problems or issues that affect entire websites.

#### [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq)

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> - Bookmarklets
> - Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

In the first case, a question about the http.conf file for a website you control is on-topic on that site, but it would not be on-topic on Stack Overflow. In fact, [Apache http.conf allow intranet](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19501/apache-http-conf-allow-intranet) was migrated there from Stack Overflow.

In the second case, a question about programming in Facebook would not be on-topic there, as questions there are about using Facebook, not creating a Facebook application, which would be on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Simplifying, the topics are:

- Pro Webmasters
  Web servers you control
- Web Applications
  Web sites that works like desktop applications
- Stack Overflow
  Programming, and tools used from programmers